# VB Checking amount in SQL table and updating table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, validation

I need some help with my validation. What I'm supposed to do is check weather the number in the textbox is greater than or less than the quantity (stored in an SQL table called inventory) for that specific item (selected from the drop downlist). If the number in the textbox is greater than then quantity for that item then a message pops up saying that there isn't enough quantity for that item. If the number is less than the quantity in the SQL table for that item then it updates that quantity for that item. What my problem is, is that my validation isn't going to my second validation. It's like its stuck at the first if statement and I don't know how to fix it. I feel like its something very simple but I just can't put my finger on it. Here's my code:

```
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select itemID, quantity From Inventory", con)
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    Try
        If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then DT.Rows.Clear()
        DA.Fill(DT)

        With DropDownList1
            .DataSource = DT
            .DataTextField = "itemID"
            .DataValueField = "quantity"
            .DataBind()
            .Items.Insert(0, "Please Select a Customer")
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim PurchaseQuantity, UP, SL As String

    PurchaseQuantity = TextBox1.Text

    Dim cmdUpdate As New SqlCommand("Update Inventory SET quantity = @p1 where price = @p2", con)

    With cmdUpdate.Parameters
        .Clear()
        .AddWithValue("@p1", PurchaseQuantity)
        .AddWithValue("@p2", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    End With

    Dim cmdSelect As New SqlCommand("Select quantity From Inventory where itemID = @p1", con)

    With cmdSelect.Parameters
        .Clear()
        .AddWithValue("@p1", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    End With

    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        UP = cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery
        SL = cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    If PurchaseQuantity > SL Then
        MsgBox("There is not enough quantity for this item", vbExclamation, "Error")
    Else
        If PurchaseQuantity < SL Then
            MsgBox("Inventory is updated", vbExclamation, "Error")
            UP -= PurchaseQuantity

        End If
    End If
```

Comment: I'd like to congratulate you on being the first VB.NET poster I've seen so far this year making correct use of paramterized queries.

Comment: Unfortunately - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Think there might be two little issues here.  1) PurchaseQuantity is a string, and your attempting to do an athematic comparison. 2) The result of ExcecuteScaler is an Object, best idea here is to turn on Option strict

Comment: More on setting `AddWithValue()` on fire: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: `.Items.Insert(0, "Please Select a Customer")` Shouldn't that refer to selecting a product, not a customer? Nor does this dropdown have a "price" column - as reflected in the first answer. And develop good habits. Names like DropDownList1 are useless and hinder understanding (and debugging) of your code.

Comment: `"Update Inventory SET quantity = @p1 where price = @p2"` This makes no sense. Why would you change the quantity in the Inventory table to the purchase quantity? Why would you be checking for the price column being equal to the quantity that is the value of the DropDownList1?

Comment: What type is the itemID in the Inventory table? Is this the primary key of this table?

Comment: @Dai Parameterized, yes but please don't compliment `AddWithValue` for Sql Server.

Comment: ^ Mary really illustrates here why you should always name parameters for what they are instead of meaningless values like `@p1` and `@p2`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're seeing the error "There is not enough quantity for this item"?

I see a few problems:

```
Update Inventory SET quantity = @p1 where price = @p2
```

should be:

```
Update Inventory SET quantity = quantity - @p1 where itemID = @p2
```

Also, the order of the commands is backwards. The `SELECT` should happen before the `UPDATE`. (Otherwise, you're deducting the quantity from your inventory, THEN checking that you have enough to fill the order.)

Also, this whole operation should be transaction-bounded. You're open to a race condition, of sorts, with the current code. (If (2) simultaneous orders are placed, you could end up with a negative inventory quantity.) Or, at least, put a check constraint on the table (Inventory.quantity > 0) so it forces a SQL Exception in VB and halts the update.

Comment: Shane P, The Error I keep seeing is indeed "there is not enough quantity for this item". I want to see the error "Inventory is updated" because that's when the amount typed into the textbox is deducted from the quantity stored in the sql table. Also, I tried what you suggested and I'm still seeing the error "there is not enough quantity for this item" on the second if statement.

Comment: Ok. In that case, I would put a break point in the code on: `cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar`. When the debugger stops there, run a SELECT statement manually in SQL (via SSMS) and check the quantity on the item you're about to select. Step through it from there.

Comment: Thank you! When I ran the debugger there was something wrong with my select statement and when I tested in SQL it kept coming up as a NULL. Turned out, I needed to select the SUM of quantity. After that I put the update statement in my validation and then placed the whole thing in my try catch. I also added a variable to connect to my sql command. Then everything started working correctly. Again, thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.